# Nokogiri scraper not sourcing properly

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, httparty

I'm trying to build a scraper for a web page for data transfer, and hitting a sourcing issue.

```rb
require 'nokogiri'
require 'byebug'
require 'httparty'
require "open-uri"

def scraper
  url = "https://page text replaced for privacy"
  

  unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(url, verify: false)
  parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page, nil, Encoding::UTF_8.to_s)

  items = Array.new
  products = parsed_page.css("div.product-column > div.row")    

  products.each do |product|
    product = {
      byebug
      summary: product.css("div.summary> a").value
      # image: product.css("div.photo>a.img-responsive").attribute("src").value,
      byebug

    }
    items << product
    puts "Added #{product[:summary]}"
    # puts "Added #{product[:image]}"
  end
end

scraper
```

When I run `byebug` on the first line of the `.each` loop  I get this error:

```
scraper.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
scraper.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end
    }
scraper.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input
```

I think I'm struggling to grab it properly. Any ideas?

Comment: try to move byebug out of `product`, `product` is a hash.

Comment: Sure, but then all I get is the deprecation warning that HTTParty spits out when Nokogiri is used with it: `[DEPRECATION] HTTParty will no longer override `response#nil?`. This functionality will be removed in future versions. Please, add explicit check `response.body.nil? || response.body.empty?`. For more info refer to: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/568`. No output available, which is why I think I'm screwing up the css drill-down.

Comment: The easiest way to see if your css selectors are whats causing you issues is to just remove HTTParty for the time being. Try manually download the html data to disk and reading the file from disk. Then you can make sure your parsing is correct first.